# Gitversion doesn't bump minor version when release branch is created

Tags: git-flow, gitversion

According to the documentation of GitVersion for GitFlow, the minor version of the develop branch should be bumped when a release branch is created.
As far as I understood it, this should happen automagically?
(https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/) - See Minor/Major release branches

I'm currently using GitVersion 3.6.5 *(as this is the version installed with the VSTS GitVersion task)*

I created a small test repository as follows:

- git init
- [master] touch helloworld.txt
- [master] git add --all
- [master] git commit -m "Added file"
- [master] git tag 0.1.0
- [master] git checkout -b develop
- [develop] touch helloworld.txt
- [develop] git add --all
- [develop] git commit -m "updated file"
- [develop] gitversion --> Reports 0.2.0.unstable.# (OK)
- [develop] git checkout -b release/0.2.0
- [release/0.2.0] touch helloworld.txt
- [release/0.2.0] git add --all
- [release/0.2.0] git commit -m "Updated file"
- [release/0.2.0] gitversion --> Reports 0.2.0.beta.# (OK)
- [release/0.2.0] git checkout develop
- [develop] touch helloworld.txt
- [develop] git add --all
- [develop] git commit -m "updated file again"
- [develop] gitversion --> Reports 0.2.0.unstable.# (WRONG)

That last gitversion command, i expected it to report 0.3.0.unstable.#, because there exists a release branch for 0.2.0

Why isn't develop reporting an increase in minor version after I created the release branch and committed to it?!

Answer (score 0):

After testing the same flow with GitVersion 4.0.0-beta13, it correctly reports develop to be 0.3.0 instead of 0.2.0

Now i just need to figure out a way to incorporate 4.0.0 into our vsts build process

Edit:

Workaround for VSTS / TFS icm with GitVersion task:
https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/1160#issuecomment-381517122